# Calling a function inside if statement in python

Tags: python, mqtt

I am trying to run lines of codes to open and close my blind using a stepper motor using python.

After successfully connecting to the mqtt server, I would like to call out a blind_up function if payload is ON and blind_down when payload is OFF.

Appreciate your help.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pinListUp = [4, 17, 27, 22]
pinListDown = [22, 27, 17, 4]

def blind_up():
    for pin in pinListUp:
        GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(pin, 0)

    seq = [ [1,0,0,0],
            [1,1,0,0],
            [0,1,0,0],
            [0,1,1,0],
            [0,0,1,0],
            [0,0,1,1],
            [0,0,0,1],
            [1,0,0,1] ]

    for i in range(512):
        for halfstep in range(8):
                for pin in range(4):
                    GPIO.output(pinListUp[pin], seq[halfstep][pin])
                time.sleep(0.001)

def blind_down():
    for pin in pinListDown:
        GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(pin, 0)

    seq = [ [1,0,0,0],
            [1,1,0,0],
            [0,1,0,0],
            [0,1,1,0],
            [0,0,1,0],
            [0,0,1,1],
            [0,0,0,1],
            [1,0,0,1] ]

    for i in range(512):
        for halfstep in range(8):
                for pin in range(4):
                    GPIO.output(pinListDown[pin], seq[halfstep][pin])
                time.sleep(0.001)



# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("switch/bedroom/blind")

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

    if msg.payload == "ON":
       blind_up

    if msg.payload == "OFF":
       blind_down


client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("192.168.1.21", 1883, 60)

# Blocking call that processes network traffic, dispatches callbacks and
# handles reconnecting.
# Other loop*() functions are available that give a threaded interface and a
# manual interface.
GPIO.cleanup()
client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: can you explain what is happening now in your code. What is and is not working? What errors (if any) are you receiving? It's not clear what the *problem* is in your code right now? You explained what you are trying to do, but you haven't indicated what is not working?

Comment: add ()  to blind_up and blind_down when you want to run them: blind up() and blind_down() will actually call the function

Comment: You need to call your function using matching parenthesis `()`. Without them you are simply _referencing_ the function objects.

Comment: @9.0 You owe me a soda :-)

Comment: cool  @ChristianDean

Comment: The code is working now. I just needed to put matching parenthesis when calling the function to the if statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add parentheses to your function calls:

```
   if msg.payload == "ON":
       blind_up()  # fix this line

   if msg.payload == "OFF":
       blind_down()  # and this line
```

Comment: @CharlesDalid you might want to change the second `if` to `elif`, and don't forget to accept the answer if you find it useful by clicking the tick under the votes on the left side of the answer